# etiquette/rules regarding acknowledgements and co-authoring of papers?

Tags: authorship, collaboration, acknowledgement

I have never published a paper before but I am wondering in the case of a collaboration, how this collaboration should be acknowledged to the reader in different situations.

Specifically, I am wondering whether there is an (internationally accepted?) "**rule-book of academic etiquette**" with a set of rules regarding questions such as:

1. If person A has contributed more than person B to a paper, how should this be made clear to the readers?
2. If person A has contributed more than person B, where is the line between B being recognized as a co-author, or simply thanked in the acknowledgements?
3. If person A has supplied all the theoretical/mathematical analysis, and person B all the empirical analysis in a paper, how should this be communicated to the reader?

**Are there standardized rules about questions like this? If so, is there some kind of resource I could consult?**

Comment: I think this varies a bit (well, a lot) by subject. There are some standardised rules for IEEE, I think.

Comment: I might be misremembering who does what. Here's a list: http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html